# Const number of words in a text

Tags: c, string

I tried to write a program for counting number of words in a text that taken from a file. I have a problem, the compiler can not find my file however I put this file in project folder.
what can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int words(const char sentence[ ]);

int main(void) {
    char sentence[100];
    FILE *cfPtr;

    if ( (cfPtr = fopen("C programming.dat", "r")) == NULL ) {
        printf( "File could not be opened\n" );
    }
    else {
        fscanf(cfPtr, "%s", sentence);
    }

    words(sentence);
    printf("%d", words(sentence));
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int words(const char sentence[ ]) {
    int i, length = 0, count = 0, last = 0;
    length = strlen(sentence);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (sentence[i] == ' ' || sentence[i] == '\t' || sentence[i] == '\n')
            count++;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: try to not use spaces in file name

Comment: You may want to format your code so that it's easier to read.

Comment: how about you try creating a file with your program and searching your harddrive for it to see where the working directory happens to be?

Comment: Try putting the entire directory.  Ex.  fp=fopen("c:\\test.txt", "w");

Comment: Also, in your word counting function, if there is more than one space between words, every space will be counted as an extra word. Not sure if that's what you wanted...

Comment: @SamIam Although usually you can find it your new file if you just look around the general area containing your workspace.

Comment: Try adding `system("dir");` to your program, and see what it says about the directory and the files in it.

Comment: Try changing the working directory of your project. Or provide the whole path.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not in the working directory (the folder your program is in) you need to specify the entire file path. On a Linux machine this would be something like `"/home/your-user-name/Desktop/text.txt"`. For a Windows machine it would be `"c:\\your\\file\path\\text.txt"`. If the file is in your working directory and the program still cannot find it, then it probably doesn't like the white space in the file name. Try naming it `CProgramming.dat` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to improve usability of your program, accepting a filename as optional parameter

```
int main(ant argc, char *argv[]) {
    char sentence[100];
    const char *filename = "C programming.dat";
    FILE *cfPtr;

    if (argc == 2)
       filename = argv[1];

    if ( (cfPtr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL ) {
        printf( "File '%s' could not be opened\n", filename );
    }
    else {
        int total = 0;
        while (fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, cfPtr))
           total += words(sentence);
        printf("%d", total);
        fclose(cfPtr);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
...
```

note: untested

Comment: Thank you... my problem about opening the file has been solved.But I have another problem, the words function could not count words, why every time it answer zero?

Comment: I could debug your code, but I'm sure it will be far more useful to you to learn how to debug by yourself. C programming (or any other language) is **so much** difficult - and unproductive - without a debugger available... Do you know how to start the debugger ?

Comment: yes... I use "visual studio" for debuging, but I think the cod has problem.

Comment: and you can't understand why words(sentence); always return 0 ? Or there is some other problem ? like the file is empty, etc etc